# Visual C++ 2017 + Qt5 - can't enable webkit in Qt Project Settings

Tags: visual-c++, qt5, qtwebkit, visual-c++-2017

When I try to include WebKit Libraries in MSVC 2017  "WebKit" and "WebKit Widgets" checkboxes are disabled, even though I've selected them to be installed.

[image]

I've tried different versions of Qt from 5.6 to 5.9beta.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Comment: I think webkit is not avaliable in community edition, only in enterprise.

Comment: @eyllanesc : Thanks bud! It worked! I am not sure why I wasn't able to Google this out!

Comment: I am posting this answer, please mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt webkit module is no longer available in Qt5, you must use the Qt WebEngine module, the following link shows the Qt official documentation procedure: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Answer (score 2):

As @eyllanesc has suggested, I should have just checked the portability guide:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

There are a couple of more things worth noting for everyone who tries to use Qt on Visual Studio 2017:

- You should use version 5.9
- Make sure to add all of the library and include paths manually
- If linker starts screeching that it can't find any webkit classes, add Qt5WebEngine(d)*.lib libraries manually to the project (Qt5WebEngineWidgets(d).lib , Qt5WebEngined.lib etc. (use the lib files with the "d" at the end of the name if you're using the debug version)
- Make sure you've selected version 5.9 in QtVSTools -> Qt Options as a defeault Qt version, and make sure you have that version selected in your QtVsTools -> Qt Project Settings

Comment: Done. I've just noticed you've posted a proper answer :-)